# xlwt on ubuntu installs but does not import

Tags: python

xlwt installs in the following path:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

successfully with `pip` or `apt-get` or `easy_install`.

However, when I try to import, it gives an error `no module named xlwt`.

All the relevant answers on this site say to `pip install`, but xlwt is already installed. As a workaround, I added the dist packages to my python path. Why is it not searching in dist packages?

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 and python 2.7

Comment: Are you using virtualenv?

Comment: No, is that the only way to fix it, thx for you reply

Comment: don't know how to use virtualenv, but will go study, any tips? thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For python and django related projects it is always preferred to use virtualenv!

1. sudo pip install virtualenv
2. To create virtualenv:

   `virtualenv my_env`
3. To activate virtual env:

   `source my_env/bin/activate`
4. pip install xlwt

Ref: http://pythoncentral.io/how-to-install-virtualenv-python/

Comment: everytime i install python package/module, do i type source my_env/bin/activate

Comment: It is mandatory to activate venv when u are installing a new package or while the running the program!

Comment: if i open the shell it works, but when i run my program in eclipse, still import error?

Comment: ok so in my program should how do i activate virtualenv? (sorry first time)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41335961/using-virtualenv-with-eclipse

Comment: and will other imports in program work still or do i have to  reinstall all modules already installed?thx

Comment: Check it out! I have given something to start on. And also don't forget to  upvote and accept the answer, it will help others who are stuck on the same issue..

Comment: add --use-site-package

Answer (score 0):

set-up eclipse to look in virtualenv (import errors in eclipse)
modules installed in dist packages, ubuntu (ex. xlwt)

create virtualenv as answered by Abijith Mg, 
BUT add
    (see below)

```
virtualenv my_env--use-site-package 

source my_env/bin/activate

pip install xlwt
```

(so you can set-up eclipse and only need to add new modules to virtualenv)

go to window menu in eclipse
   preferences
   pyDev on the left
   interpreters
   python interpreter

new folder

select your virtualenv path to point to site-packages
   apply